# Jfrog + SBT unathorized error with valid credentials

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, artifactory, ivy

My problem is that I'm getting unathorized error from jfrog artifactory

[image]

I have credentials file in ~/.ivy2/.credentials, credentials correct 100% because I can access JFrog from UI with this credentials.

I've tried everything:

- Added SBT_CREDENTIALS to system env variables
- Provided path to credentials as VM variable in Intellij Idea
- Tried to run SBT server via PowerShell using command `java --% -server -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.boot.credentials=C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.ivy2\.credentials -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin\sbt-launch.jar"`
- Provided same params as VM options via Intellij IDEA

No matter what I'm doing I'm getting unathorized from my JFrog artifactory. Maybe there is something that I'm missing, could you please help me?

Comment: Have you tried calling the exact URL used by SBT (that you can see in SBT error message) with cURL for instance and see what happens with and without your credentials? (You can pass them to curl through basic Auth or a bearer token if any).

Comment: I can access JFrog using curl or Postman successfully. So I guess my credentials missing somehow when I start sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

1. Create `.credentials` file in .sbt folder
2. Add this data to `.credentials`

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=<host>
user=<username>
password=<pass>
```

3. Create `credentials.sbt` in `.sbt/1.0/plugins`
4. Add `credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")` into `credentials.sbt` file

Those steps solved problem for me!

Comment: This worked for me.